# locationManager didExitRegion or locationManager didEnterRegion never called

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

     if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]){

        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

        self.locationManager.delegate = self;

        CLLocationCoordinate2D companyCenter;

        companyCenter.latitude = 23.126272;

        companyCenter.longitude = 113.395568;


        CLRegion* fkit = [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:companyCenter
                                                           radius:500 identifier:@"fkit"];
        [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:fkit];

    }else{
        NSLog(@"not support");
    }

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Error : %@",error);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager monitoringDidFailForRegion:(CLRegion *)region withError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Region monitoring failed with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(nonnull CLRegion *)region
{
    NSLog(@"Entered Region - %@", region.identifier);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(nonnull CLRegion *)region
{
    NSLog(@"Entered Enter Region - %@", region.identifier);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"Started monitoring %@ region", region.identifier);
}
```

Above is my code. I run in simulator without location,and then set custome location(23.126272,113.395568) in Debug ->location item ,  and it never call didEnterRegion delegate . anyone can help me ?
PS：my Xcode is 7.1.1, and Console log "Started monitoring fkit region"

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a few steps. You have to add an entry to your info.plist declaring that you want to use location services while your app is in the foreground, (Using the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` key) and then you need to check to see if you have permission, and ask for it if you don't.

Do a search on the string "Requesting Permission to Use Location Services" in the Xcode docs for more information.

Comment: I add this key ,and simulator ask me to allow location ,and it has nothing.

Comment: So try it on an actual device

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in didStartMonitoringForRegion

```
[self.locationManager requestStateForRegion:yourregion];
```